# Other suggested sites

Tags: feature-request

When suggesting an alternative site for a question, it only suggests the meta site.  Is it possible to add in more sites, like movies, anime, and others?

Comment: What you're asking about are called [**migration paths**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/migration-paths). At present, only moderators can migrate questions outside of SFF/meta.SFF, and few enough questions need to be migrated that we can easily cope with this workload.

Comment: Previous questions have been asked about this: [specific to M&TV](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8161/migration-to-mtv-reopening-the-discussion) (the most recent incarnation of that discussion), [specific to Anime & Manga](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3347/do-we-want-a-straight-migration-path-to-animemanga) - both have the consensus that **it's not necessary to add migration paths**.

Comment: Please do not delete useful questions!